# Navigate through TabItem using MVVm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Assum that I have 3 user Control(TIShowNames,TIEnterCode,TIShowFactor).
they have their views and their corresponding viewModel.

all these 3, are in mainwindowView.

Here is my mainwindowView Xaml:

```
<Controls:TransitionPresenter Name="transContainer" Grid.Row="2" RestDuration="0:0:1" IsLooped="False" Transition="{StaticResource SlideTransition}">
        <TabControl Name="TCMain" Background="#00FFFFFF" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0 -5 0 0 ">



            <TabItem Name="TIShowNames" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <views:NameView x:Name="NameViewElement" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="TIEnterCode" Visibility="Collapsed">
                 <views:CodeView x:Name="CodeViewElement"  />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="TIShowFactor" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <views:FactorDetailView x:Name="FactorDetailViewElement"  />
            </TabItem> 

        </TabControl>
    </Controls:TransitionPresenter>
```

In my old Programming style i used to use this line of code for navigating through tab items(without any pattern):

```
 private void ChangeTabItemTo(TabItem TI)
    {

        transContainer.ApplyTransition("TCMain", "TCMain");
        TCMain.SelectedItem = TI;
    }
```

I have a btn show  in "TIShowNames", so when i clicks on that it has to go to "TIShowFactor". 
In MVVM, ViewModel does not know any thing about view(this item tab is in its parent view!!!). so how he can change selected Tab Item without violating MVVM??

Another Try:
Changing Selectedindex wont work because of this error:

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Index'
>   property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel'
>   (HashCode=22018304)'. BindingExpression:Path=AAA;
>   DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=22018304); target element is
>   'TabControl' (Name=''); target property is 'IsSelected' (type
>   'Boolean')"

**Update**:

Controls:TransitionPresenter is from Fluid DLL

**Update**:

I want to hide tab item's header so no one can click the header and navigatoin through header is possibe only via btns in usercontrols

Answer (score 2):

You could define a `DataTemplate` per view model type in the view:

```
<TabControl Name="TCMain"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel}"
            Background="#00FFFFFF" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0 -5 0 0 ">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NameViewViewModel}">
                        <views:NameView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CodeViewViewModel}">
                        <views:CodeView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FactorDetailViewModel}">
                        <views:FactorDetailView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

...and bind the `SelectedItem` property to a source property that you set in your view model, e.g.:

```
public object ViewModel
{
    get { return _vm; }
    set { _vm = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
...
ViewModel = new CodeViewViewModel(); //displays the CodeView
```

Comment: You should probably also mention that this requires the tab view-models to be added to a list property on the main view-model, and that `TabControl.ItemsSource` is bound to that property.  Just in case it isn't obvious from your example code.

Comment: I though it was :)

Comment: TabControl.ItemsSource should set to ObservableCollection<T>. what can be replaced instead of T? viewmodels are not same.

Comment: "ViewModel = new CodeViewViewModel(); " will just work when you are in the mainwindowviewmodel. it is not accessible from for example "NameViewViewModel"

Comment: You can use ObservableCollection<object> or ObservableCollection<T> where T is a base class or an interface that all view model types implemnent.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on mm8's answer, this is how I'd do it:

First of all, I would create a BaseViewModel class to be inherited by every view model that will represent each tab of the TabControl.

I like to implement it as an abstract class with an abstract string property called "Title", so I can dynamically create the tabs and display their names (or titles). This class would also implement the NotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public abstract string Title { get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then I would create each view model inheriting from this base view model. for example:

```
public class NameViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public override string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return "Name";
        }
    }
}
```

You would do the same for the other view models, only changing the "title" property of each of them.

Now I would create the MainView of the application and its corresponding view model.

The MainViewModel would have a collection of BaseViewModels and a "CurrentViewModel" (of type BaseViewModel) and would add all the view models you want to its collection on its constructor, like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public override string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return "Main";
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> _viewModels;
    public ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> ViewModels
    {
        get { return _viewModels; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _viewModels)
            {
                _viewModels = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    } 

    private BaseViewModel _currentViewModel;
    public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentViewModel)
            {
                _currentViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }                
        }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>();
        ViewModels.Add(new NameViewModel());
        ViewModels.Add(new CodeViewModel());
        ViewModels.Add(new FactorDetailViewModel());
    }
}
```

Finally, your main view would be similar to what mm8 posted:

(Notice the differences from my code to mm8's code: (1) You need to set the DisplayMemberPath of the TabControl to the "Title" property of the BaseViewModels and (2) You need to set the DataContext of the Window to your MainViewModel)

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="TCMain"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Title"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
            Background="#00FFFFFF" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0 -5 0 0 ">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                        <ContentControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NameViewModel}">
                                <local:NameView />
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CodeViewModel}">
                                <local:CodeView />
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FactorDetailViewModel}">
                                <local:FactorDetailView />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentControl.Resources>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now it should work as expected. Everytime you change the active tab of the TabControl, the SelectedItem property of the control will change to the corresponding view model, which will be templated as its corresponding view.

This approach is called "View Model First" (instead of View First), by the way.

**EDIT**

If you want to have a button on one of the view models that has a command to change the current view model, this is how you do it:

I suppose you are familiarized with Josh Smith's RelayCommand. If you are not, just search for its implementation on the web.

You will need to create an ICommand property on your MainViewModel, which will be responsible to change the "CurrentViewModel" property:

```
private ICommand _showFactorDetailCommand;
public ICommand ShowFactorDetailCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_showFactorDetailCommand == null)
        {
            _showFactorDetailCommand = new RelayCommand(p => true, p => show());
        }
        return _showFactorDetailCommand;
    }
}

private void show()
{
    CurrentViewModel = ViewModels.Single(s => s.Title == "Factor");
}
```

The show() method above simply searches the collection of view models that has the title "Factor" and set it to the CurrentViewModel, which in turn will be the Content of the ContentControl that acts as the ContentTemplate of your TabControl inside your main view.

Remember that your FactorDetailViewModel should be implemented as follows:

```
public class FactorDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public override string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return "Factor";
        }
    }
}
```

The button inside your "NameView" will bind to this command which is a property of "MainViewModel" using RelativeSource binding:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ShowFactorDetailCommand}" Content="Show Factor" Height="20" Width="60"/>
```

You could make this command more generic, passing the title of the view model you would like to navigate to as the command parameter:

```
private ICommand _showCommand;
public ICommand ShowCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_showCommand == null)
        {
            _showCommand = new RelayCommand(p => true, p => show(p));
        }
        return _showCommand;
    }
}

private void show(p)
{
    var vm = (string)p;
    CurrentViewModel = ViewModels.Single(s => s.Title == vm);
}
```

Then on your views, pass the Command Parameter too:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ShowCommand}" Content="Show Factor" CommandParameter="Factor" Height="20" Width="60"/>
```

Finally, to hide your TabItems completely, you need to set the ItemContainerStyle of your TabControl so that the Visibility of your TabItems has the value of "Collapsed".

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: this maybe okay when you click on tab items header. But this is my situation:
I have a btn "show" in "TIShowNames", so when i clicks on that it has to go to "TIShowFactor".
This btn is in my usercontrol and does know any thing about tabcntrol or tab item

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my answer explaining how you can achieve that.